# role specific command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

role specific command yes its working finally got it.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('?')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator")
async def hello(ctx):
    await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `discord.ext.commands` extension, which offers a [`has_any_role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_any_role) decorator.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot('?')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_any_role("Admin", "Moderator")
async def hello(ctx):
    await bot.say("Hello {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```

Comment: Hi Patrick yes your code works. If any member who have that Admin and mod role uses commands it works. and if Non Admin members uses that commands it not works, but i keep getting errors in bash when non members uses that command. So is it possible to add a line if non Admin member uses that command they should get something like `You are not a ADMIN`

Comment: @Demotry See the documentation section on [error handling](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling)

Comment: yes i checked your link but no success. so please is it possible to get a return message for above code.